# How to get different random numbers?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Non repeating random number array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052519/non-repeating-random-number-array)

I have a String array with many elements (as I haven't still finished the Application, I don't know exactly the number), maybe about 200. I would like to get 20 random elements of this array, but being certain that every random element occurs only once, like, I don't want to get in those 20 elements the 5th element (for example) twice. How can I do this?

Comment: I've tried nothing since I can't work out how to do this.

Comment: Well, you can increase the seed as much as you can. It still does not guarantee that you wont get the same number, but the possibility is really low i.e. if you take like 10mil seed to 200 length string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it's Java.
If that's right you could do something like:

```
public void getRandomElementsOfArray(String[] array)
{
    int maxLength = 200; // Insert length of your array
    int[] usedRandoms;
    String[] randomElements = String[20];
    int random = new Random().nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i<21; i++) // Loops are NOT my strongest point. you'd better check this
    {
        while(random > maxLength || random < 0 || !Arrays.asList(usedRandoms).contains(random)) // Loop while random is smaller then 0 (the smallest index) or bigger then the length of your array or already used
        {
            random = new Random();
        }


        randomElements[i] = array[random];
        usedRandoms[i] = random;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Actually the !usedRandoms.asList.contains(random) doesn't work beacuse of asList. Eclipse proposes me to change it to length but it doesn't work either. What do you think I can do?

Comment: Oops, went wrong!! See edit I will make now!

Comment: `Arrays.asList(usedRandoms).contains(random)` will work @Cippo

Comment: Thanks!!!! I think it will work now!!!

Comment: Actually you can't initialize an int giving type Random(), you have to do this: int pippo=new Random().nexInt();

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you follow a fairly direct strategy. You need a set elements that you have already selected -in your situation a HashSet might be appropriate, Given the string array size of X:

- Select a element between 0 and X-1
- Check if it is in the Selected set, if so start again
- Add it to the Selected set
- if you have selected sufficient elements break out, otherwise start again

Answer (score 0):

Find the below code generate the random numbers

```
/** Generate 10 random integers in the range 0..99. */
public final class RandomInteger {

public static final void main(String... aArgs){
log("Generating 10 random integers in range 0..99.");

//note a single Random object is reused here
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
for (int idx = 1; idx <= 10; ++idx){
  int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
  log("Generated : " + randomInt);
}

log("Done.");
}

 private static void log(String aMessage){
System.out.println(aMessage);
}
}
```