# How to make a random number but it doesn't produce the same number

Tags: java, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Random permutation of integers using a random number generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872132/random-permutation-of-integers-using-a-random-number-generator)

For example I need to make a random number from 1 to 30. But it doesn't produce the same random number. The number produced has to be different one to another.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to keep a `List` of the numbers that have been produced so that if the random number is in that list, it tries again.

Comment: You can use the techniques in this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9052519/non-repeating-random-number-array

Comment: @DevinStewart: that's extremely inefficient. Think about the number of retries it would need to generate the 30th number.

Comment: @JBNizet: True, if he is getting all 30 Numbers.  I admit your solution is more efficient, hence up voted it.

Comment: @DevinStewart It'd be more efficient even if he's only getting two numbers. And more deterministic.

Comment: @ Edward Octavianus Pakpahanplease note that if you want a number of desired value or characteristic then ITS NOT A RANDOM NUMBER!

Comment: @codeMan A random number selected from the set {1, 20, 21, 25, 30} is just as much a random number as one selected from a set of consecutive numbers. All the question asks for is a number selected at random, with equal probability, from the subset of [1, ... ,30] that has not yet been selected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a `List<Integer>` containing 1-30, shuffle it using `Collections.shuffle()`, then iterate through the list. Of course, at the end of the list, it's impossible to have a new number that hasn't been generated yet.